# NameConstraints format for UPN values

Tags: windows, certificate, smartcard, pki

I'm in the middle of building a new PKI and we are adding name constraints to our issuing CAs with all the usual suspects like DNS, IP, e-mails, directory names etc.

We have a potential smart card requirement on this project and I am trying to build this into the CA restrictions. In the very few examples I can find online, the restrictions are in the same format for those as e-mail addresses. I see things like this:

```
permitted;email.1     = .example.com
permitted;email.2     = @example.com
permitted;otherName.1 = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3;UTF8:.example.com
permitted;otherName.1 = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3;UTF8:@example.com
```

The problem with this is that email.2 is actually wrong. I had golang choke on it recently. Looking at the RFC, golang is right; there is no provision for having a "@" in the restriction.

So, I'm trying to figure out if a '@' is bogus for UPNs before I end up having to re-issue my CA again.

Has anyone actually tried such a foolhardy endeavor and succeeded?

Comment: Before you go down this potential rabbit hole, do you know the processing semantics for UPN name constraints? Or even if such a thing exists?  Name constraints for DNS, rfc822 email etc. are defined in RFC 5280, but it doesn't mention UPN.

Comment: I'm reasonably confident they exist as I've found examples online and I was able to successfully generate the restrictions above (which is to say standards-compliant programs don't freak out about them). I'm more or less resigned to having to re-issue these CAs when we get to that phase of the project.

Comment: But do programs reject certificates with UPNs that are outside of the permitted subtree in name constraint?  If not, there is no value to progressing with this.  If you have multiple relying party software, you  need to verify each one.  Also remember that this extension must be marked as critical if you are RFC 5280 compliant, therefore if an application fails to process UPN name constraints it must reject the certificate.  Lots of testing required I think!

Comment: Well, it's not like a regular TLS restriction where you have a ton of TLS implementations that may or may not support a given extension, it's just MS and they do reference UPN usage in name constraints (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/constraints-what-they-are-and-how-they-amp-8217-re-used/ba-p/1129048). You're right though, given the dearth of information on the net about nameConstraints in general and UPN constraints in particular, it'll be a ton of testing. I've basically settled (in part based on that link) to just follow the e-mail format.